# What are 'tables' in asm for MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am learning as with MIPS and doing some projects that I found online.  One such project calls for the creation of a table to store information in.  The idea is to generate random machine instructions, like bne, add, adii, and the proper values associated with them.  The project says that the table should be named optable, and or each opcode I should have name, opcode, funct, and type in the table.  The question I have is, what is meant by a table?  I am unfamiliar with tables in asm and I couldn't find any reference to tables when I searched on google.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word table is somewhat ambiguous. It could mean a hash-table but it the context of a beginning assembly tutorial they probably mean an array.

To declare an array "or rather reserve space for an array" use the `space` directive with an argument of number of bytes to reserve.

To do this, you need to think about how much space you need for each entry.

- opcode: 6 bits - store it in a single byte
- funct: 6 bits - store it in a single byte
- type: Either R, I, or J - store it in a single byte as a character 'R', 'I' or 'J'.
- name: An ASCII representation of the instruction. I looked at a list [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2008fa/MIPS_Vol2.pdf) and it appears that the longest MIPS instruction name is `ROUND.W.fmt` which with a trailing null terminator comes out to 12 characters, but just to be safe let's allocate 16 bytes per name.

Therefore, you need 19 bytes per entry in your table.

So to allocate a table to store let's say 20 such entries you need 380 bytes:

```
.data

optable: .space 380
```

To use your table in your code you first load the base address using `la` and then index in `19*(entry number) + byte-offset`. E.g. for the opcode this is `19*(entry number)`, and for name it is `19*(entry number) + 3`.

E.g.

```
.text

main:
    la $t0 optable
    sb $t1 0($t0) # store $t1 as opcode of first entry
    sb $t1 1($t0) # store $t1 as funct of first entry
    sb $t1 2($t0) # store $t1 as type of first entry
    sb $t1 3($t0) # store $t1 as first letter of name of first entry
    jr $ra
```

Comment: So, if I wanted to make a table of instructions with their opcodes, function and type, I could define that in the table itself in the data segment, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But following the pattern above if you only want to store opcodes, function and type and not name then you only need 3 bytes per entry meaning to allocate space for 20 entries you would instead use `.space 60`

Comment: What I mean is if I wanted a table with the values associated for each instruction.  So say I want my table to have the values for add and addi.  I would define the first line of the array as 
    0x616464, 0x00, 0x14, 0x52.  
This would give me the ascii name, opcode, funct, and type of instruction.  I could use this table to pull the information I need to generate the machine code once I have randomly chosen an instruction to use.  This is probably very vague and unclear.

Comment: Are you asking how you might go about hard-coding these values for a predetermined set of instructions?